# Script running problem/error - Matlab 2019b

Tags: matlab

I get this error in Matlab

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT feature as a function:
E:\feature.m

Error in images.internal.isFigureAvailable (line 9)
if feature('showFigureWindows')

Error in imtool (line 172)
  if ~images.internal.isFigureAvailable()

Error in Untitled (line 8)
imtool close all;  % Close all imtool figures.

Error in run (line 91)
evalin('caller', strcat(script, ';'));
```

It does not matter which code I run it always shows up. How can I solve it?

Comment: You can find many results on Google for your error? What have you already tried? This answer is by Mathworks itself: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93148-#answer_102496

Comment: Check if you have a file `feature.m` in your current folder, or path. You can debug it as follows: Create a new script, add a line: `feature('showFigureWindows')`, place a breakpoint, and step into `feature.m` with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB has a built in function called `feature`. `imtool` is internally trying to call this function, but instead a script you placed on `E:\feature.m` is called. Delete or rename your feature.m.